# place for general assets and layout

Tags: css, symfony

Bonjour,
i am working on a symfony 2.7 project, I have the general template of the site with its css and js and fonts etc ... i wondered where do i have to put them because it does no belong to a specific bundle. i put the general layout in app/ressources/views and i try to create a public folder in app/ressources/public but the command assets:intall just copy public ressource from existing bundle so i deduct that it should not be the good place for general assets. So i had the idea of create a bundle just for generals templates with its css images etc but i dont know if it is a good idea or if there is a better solution. what do you think about that ? 
thank u and sorry for my english.

Comment: This might not apply to your case, but I like to have at least `CoreBundle` which purpose is just that: to store common logic, services and resources. It does not, however, contain any action...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a common set of assets that you plan to reuse in other  projects, then a separate bundle is the way to go.

But if you are only talking about assets specific to this project, then you should put them in your AppBundle (which, as per the "[Best Practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html)" book, should be the only bundle in your project).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a self-contained Bundle with all your templates/resources and then expand your other bundles on it?

Comment: Yes why not that's what i intend to do but i dont know if it is the best practice

Comment: Why shouldn't it? You don't "pollute" the global `app` namespace and create well-defined dependencies among your bundles. IMHO go for it!

Comment: I have read that some people put all common asstes files in web directory manually what do you think about that ? it does not seems to be a clean solution. I think i am going to crate a CommonBundle with all my common templates/resources as you say.

Comment: I would do that only for an handful of image files (logo maybe?). For more assets or templates I think it is not the right choice. If you think this solution is right for you please accept the answer.

Comment: ok Diego lol the meaning of IMHO ? thank you for your answers

Comment: IMHO = In My Humble Opinion. Glad to be of help.

Comment: i think the common bundle it is the best solution among all solutions i 've find if you have others...

Answer (score 0):

The proper place for your project-specific assets is the web/ folder. There is no need for copying them around.